# Generate list with conditional items

Tags: perl

Is it possible to create an array with conditional items?

```
my @a = (1, ($condition) ? 2 : "no-op", 3);
```

Such that `"no-op"` is function that works such that if `$condition` is false, then I get the list `(1, 3)` but if `$condition` is true, I get `(1, 2, 3)` ?

---

**Background:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new();
$rule->or(
    $rule->new->name('*.cfg')->prune->discard,
    $rule->directory->name("_private.d")->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->name('*.t')->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->name('*.bak')->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->name('.*.bak')->prune->discard,
    $rule->new->name('.#*')->prune->discard,
);

my @files = $rule->in(".");
```

In some cases I would like to include the line

```
$rule->directory->name("_private.d")->prune->discard
```

and in other cases I would not like to exclude directory `_private.d`..

Comment: "would like to include" and "would not like to exclude" is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: `my @a = (1, $condition ? 2 : "no-op", 3);` should work

Comment: @TLP yes, but here they do not mean the same thing.. :)

Comment: @ZachLeighton I am not sure what you mean ...

Comment: `($condition)` is not the same as `$condition` the first is in list context

Comment: @ZachLeighton: no, both are in list context.  operators create context, not parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use empty list `()` to skip second element,

```
my @a = (1, ($condition ? 2 : ()), 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!... (I will be offline for some hours.. I accept it later..)

Comment: that's how I'd do it.  but some use the list repetition operator: `my @a = ( 1, (2) x !!$condition, 3 );`

Comment: @ysth yes, unfortunately it is not much shorter and is barely a common idiom unlike ternary `?:`

Comment: @ysth, It also evaluates `2` unconditionally.

Comment: yes, it can be way less efficient if the optional elements take significant time and are often omitted

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can get some readability gains using

```
my @a;
push @a, 1;
push @a, 2 if $condition;
push @a, 3;
```

In context, that would be

```
my @rules;
push @rules, $rule->new->name('*.cfg')->prune->discard;
push @rules, $rule->directory->name("_private.d")->prune->discard if $condition;
push @rules, $rule->new->name('*.t')->prune->discard;
push @rules, $rule->new->name('*.bak')->prune->discard;
push @rules, $rule->new->name('.*.bak')->prune->discard;
push @rules, $rule->new->name('.#*')->prune->discard;

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new()->or(@rules);
my @files = $rule->in(".");
```