# perl hash assigning if

Tags: perl, hash

I am assigning values to a hash like this :

```
 my $hashdt = {
            a      => $p,
            b      => $q->r,
            c      => $y,
           };
```

I want to change this so that c gets a value only if another variable, $x, is defined. If $x is not defined, c is assigned the value of $y. I can do that assignment as a separate line of code. Is there a way to do it here, in this line itself? Other keys must continue getting values as they are now.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets a value"? `undef`? Doesn't exist at all? Be more specific...

Comment: I meant 'c is assigned the value'.

Comment: And if `$x` isn't defined, then what happens? Why am I playing 20 questions with you?

Comment: The answer provided below solved my problem. He made a guess at what I was trying to do and it worked. Anyway, edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: See also [Generate list with conditional items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821728/generate-list-with-conditional-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
my $hashdt = {
            a      => $p,
            b      => $q->r,
            c      => defined($x)?$x:$y,   #you can also use '$x||$y'
           };
```

Comment: I suspect that the RHS should be `defined($x) ? $y : undef;` (where the `undef` could be `$x` instead), but the basic idea — use a conditional operator and the `defined` operator — is correct.  At least, it's correct if I've read between the lines of an unclearly specified question correctly.

Comment: `defined($x)?$x:$y` can be simplified to `$x // $y`.

Comment: Thanks @DaveCross . I wasn't aware of that. I have updated my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following will also work -

```
my $hashdt = {
            a      => $p,
            b      => $q->r,
            c      => $x || $y,
           };
```

Comment: The question asked to check if `$x` is defined. Here, you are checking that it is true. You could fix that by making it `$x // $y`.