# Is possible to use next inside of map in perl?

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, map-function

I would like to parse only headers name in `main.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a,int b){ return a+b; }
int sub(int a, int b){ return a-b; }

int main(){
    printf("%i\n",add(1,2));
}
```

So my perl script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open MAIN, $ARGV[0];

@ar = map { /#include "([^"]+)"/ ? $1 : next } <MAIN>;

#this one works (next inside for-loop, not map-loop)
for(<MAIN>){
    if(/#include "([^"]+)"/){
        push @ar2, $1;
    } else {
        next;
    }
}

print "@ar\n";
print "@ar2\n";
```

gives error:

```
Can't "next" outside a loop block
```

so is `next` possible in `map`? if so, how to fix my case?

Comment: See also [Generate list with conditional items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27821728/2173773)

Comment: Tip: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. There are other things that can be improved, but that one is crucial.

Comment: There are no more operations after your `next` in the `for` loop, so you do not actually need the `else` block at all there.

Answer (score 8):

A given iteration of `map` can return any number of scalars including zero.

```perl
my @ar = map { /#include "([^"]+)"/ ? $1 : () } <MAIN>;
```

A match with captures in list context returns the captured text on a match, and nothing on a failed match. As such, the above can be simplified.

```perl
my @ar = map { /#include "([^"]+)"/ } <MAIN>;
```

Comment: what if there will more captures in the `//`? Will the result return $1 or $2 ?

Comment: Both. You can always use the conditional operator for more control. For example, `/^(.)\1(.)\2(.)\3\z/ ? ( $1, $3 ) : ()`

Comment: but I cannot work with the `$1` then: if I use `@main_hed=map{/#include "([^"]+)"/ and abs_path($1)}<MAIN>;`, then the `$1` will remain for even failed ones. I have to use `for` instead of `map`

Comment: `/#include "([^"]+)"/ ? abs_path($1) : ()`

Comment: You could also chain `map`s. `map { abs_path($_) } map { /#include "([^"]+)"/ }`